# Android build fail with Rhodes 4.0.0

Tags: android, rhomobile, rhodes

I upgrade my Rhodes from 3.4.2 to 4.0.0 with all other parts from RhoStudio.
I updated rho_home variable and devbuild.yml with the new version, I update all the paths in rhobuild.yml.

I'm working with android sdk 17, java 6

I'm keep getting this error in compilation process:

```
cc1plus.exe: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++11"
```

Can someone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rhodes v4.0.0 is now using some NDK features that are not available in older NDK.

You need a newer Android NDK. Release 8 or newer will works.

Upgrading your application, can be useful the [migration guide available on RhoMobile doc website](http://docs.rhomobile.com/en/4.0.0/guide/apiusage).